# Tensorflow: Save History of Images from Generator

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, gan

I'm building a Generative Adversarial Network. I need to be able to save the output of the generator in some data structure, and then at each training step, sample from the current generator, as well as from the historical images. How can I do this in TensorFlow? I don't want to use a feed_dict for performance reasons.